# HTTP Handler without a response

Tags: java, service, httphandler, httpserver

I am writing a test `HTTPHandler`, and was connecting to the server I created using this test code.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        String param = URLEncoder.encode( "raghu", Constants.ENCODING_CHARSET );
        String uri = "http://127.0.0.1:" + Constants.PORT_NUMBER + "/test" + "?" + "welcome=" + param;
        URL url = new URL( uri );
        HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "application/xml" );
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setReadTimeout( 5000 );


                InputStream responseCode = conn.getInputStream();
                System.out.println();
                String toString = convertInputStreamToString( responseCode );
                System.out.println( "response-->" + toString );

        conn.disconnect();
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString( InputStream inputStream ) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        for ( int i; ( i = inputStream.read( b ) ) != -1; ) {
            out.append( new String( b, 0, i ) );
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
```

And my handler code is,

```
public class TestServiceAPI extends BaseServiceAPI {

    @Override
    public void handle( HttpExchange arg0 ) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> params = getParams( arg0 );
        System.out.println( "Inside test service---> " + params.get( "welcome" ) );
    }

}
```

So is it mandatory to send some response from the handler?
My code here stops at `InputStream responseCode = conn.getInputStream();` since that is the only way I know to fire. Please let me know if am doing it correctly or is there any other way of firing a request to the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my bad.. The answer was really very simple.

I just add this to my handler code:

```
request.sendResponseHeaders( 200, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the API, it appears you can use [connect()](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) instead of opening a stream(**test it!** I didn't).

Still - you **should** write something to the response stream to signify that the request was completed without errors. A simple "OK" will do.